# Adicionar valor a uma variável na tabela mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-update, trigger

Possuo um trigger, sempre que um valor é adicionado a tabela no mysql eu pego o valor antigo(OLD) e adiciono a outra tabela, porém gostaria de melhorar isso adicionando os valores a mesma tabela mas sem duplicar, pois possuo 3 colunas, ID, NOME, SOBRENOME, caso eu faca isso o ID será duplicado, existe alguma maneira de fazer com que o ID por exemplo, seja ID+999?

```
 DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER working
BEFORE UPDATE
   ON name FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

INSERT INTO name
   ( id,
    name,
    adress)
   VALUES
   ( OLD.id+9999,
    OLD.name
    OLD.adress);

END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Recomendo que você coloque algum código de como você está fazendo ou explique com alguma print o que você deseja fazer... O Stack Overflow não é para este tipo de dúvidas

Comment: Adicionei o código do trigger para que fique melhor

Comment: Não vejo nenhuma justificativa para tal procedimento. Repense seu problema e analise a melhor solução para ele que não me parece, sinceramente, ser essa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bem simples até...

> update Tabela set campo = campo+100 where id = xxx;

se o valor de campo for 120, ele será de 220.

Comment: Boa tarde Michel, obrigado pela resposta, funcionaria no caso de um trigger? adicionei o código do mesmo para que fique melhor a visualização do problema

Comment: Sim, mas vc teria um problemão com os indices automáticos da sua tabela, vc precisa atualizar os indices e corre o risco de ter problemas mais a frente com isso

Comment: Que tipo de problema poderia ocorrer neste caso? por ver das dúvidas seria melhor adicionar os valores antigos a outra tabela, certo?

Comment: na verdade eu nao entendi porque vc nao atualiza o registro e mantem o index, ou cria uma coluna de controle proprio e deixa o index em paz.

Comment: se voce edita o index, todo o relacionamento que o registro tem em outras tabelas se perdem, se vc está no index 11, 12, 13, 14, e adiciona mil ao 11, ele vai seguir do 1012, 1013, e se vc adicionar 1000 aou 13, ja encontrará um index igual, ou seja, index é coisa pro banco administrar

Comment: Infelizmente não posso atualizar o registro pois o mesmo recebe o update justamente para que o primeiro registro não seja visualizado por outras pessoas, preciso pensar em alguma maneira de adicionar o valor antigo a mesma tabela mas sem duplicar